# Populating ERB template with hash fails with symbol as array index

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to populate a json string using a hash that is built in a chef recipe but keep hitting the error 'Symbol as array index'.  My searches on stackoverflow and google have lead me nowhere and am just curious what's going on here.  I'm not great with Ruby so please forgive me if the code is a bit off.

Attribute file:

```
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache] = Hash.new
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:type] = "LocalFile"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:name] = "Apache Logs"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:path_expression] = "/var/log/httpd/*.log"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] = Array.new
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] << "/var/log/httpd/access.log*"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] << "/var/log/httpd/error.log*"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] << "/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] << "/var/log/httpd/access_log"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] << "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:category] = "test-httpd"
```

Template erb file:

```
{
  "api.version": "v1",
  "sources": [
    <% sources.each do |source| %>
    {
      "sourceType" : "<%= source[:type] %>",
      "name": "<%= source[:name] %>",
      "pathExpression": "<%= source[:path_expression] %>",
      <% if defined?(source[:blacklist]) %>
      "blacklist": [
        <% source[:blacklist].each do |listed, index| %>
        <%  if index < source[:blacklist].length - 1 %>
        "<%= listed %>",
        <%  else %>
        "<%= listed %>"
        <%  end %>
        <% end %>
      ],
      <% end %>
      "category": "<%= source[:category] %>"
    },
    <% end %>

...
```

Recipe Code:

```
template '/opt/SumoCollector/sources.json' do
  source 'sources.json.erb'
  variables({
      :sources => node[:server][:sumologic][:sources]
  })
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of chef attributes is a bit wrong. They are not hashes, but smarter, so you don't have to initialize them as Hash. **Remove** the line:

```
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache] = Hash.new
```

Also it's better to initialize array attributes in 1 operation:

```
node.default[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache][:blacklist] = [
  '/var/log/httpd/access.log*',
  '/var/log/httpd/error.log*',
  '/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log',
  '/var/log/httpd/access_log',
  '/var/log/httpd/error_log'
]
```

Your error "Symbol as array index" comes from that in your case

```
<% sources.each do |source| %>
  "sourceType" : "<%= source[:type] %>",
  [...]
<% end %>
```

`source` is actually an array `[:apache, <hash-like-object>]`, so calling `source[:type]` fails.

*sources* is actually a hash-like collection of attributes and you should handle it accordingly. If you change the line to be like that

```
<% sources.each do |key, source| %>
```

everything will work. Here *key* will be ":apache" and *source* will be equal to `node[:server][:sumologic][:sources][:apache]`.

Comment: OP has showed it, it's the variables attribute of the template resource. Thoose  variables passed to the erb templates are local to the template instance, the syntax is  `@source[]` to access them (I'm unsure of what it gives with a global scope insted of local one.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I read up on that and understand a bit more of what I was doing.  Everything is working correctly but I'm running into a problem accessing the blacklist with source[:blacklist].  puts source[:blacklist] gives me an array `"[\"/var/log/httpd/access.log*\", \"/var/log/httpd/error.log*\", \"/var/log/httpd/ssl_request_log\", \"/var/log/httpd/access_log\", \"/var/log/httpd/error_log\"]"` so I'm working through that issue now.